# Get substring of regex from string

Tags: bash, shell

I am using a bash script to parse logs and need to extract a substring.

My string is something like this -

```
TestingmkJHSBD,MFV from testing:2.6.1.566-978.7 testing
```

How can I extract this string using bash

Comment: What has failed for you so far?  Can you update your question with sample code? Based on the log output in your question,  something like `awk '{print $3}' <<<"TestingmkJHSBD,MFV FROM image/something/docker:2.6.1.566-978.7 testing"` might suffice.

Comment: I just added the sample text infront but it could be ~100 lines and I just want to extract this part - FROM image/something/docker:2.6.1.566-978.7

Comment: Perhaps change the awk to include only line matching 'FROM image':    `awk '/FROM image/ {print $3}' <<<"TestingmkJHSBD,MFV FROM image/something/docker:2.6.1.566-978.7 testing"`

Comment: ^^ This didnt work for me. 
Im using another text string - "bdkjf asfjkklsdfsg FROM image/something/docker:2.6.1.566-978.7 testing " --> This just prints FROM

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk '
    /FROM image/ {
        if (match($0, /image[^[:space:]]+/))
            print(substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH))
    }
' logfile
```

- The regex `image[^[:space:]]+` matches a substring which starts with
  `image` and followed by non-space character(s).
- Then the awk variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` are assigned to the position
  and the length of the matched substring.

Answer (score 1):

Another awk option:

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /FROM image/) {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^image/) {print $i} }}' <<<"TestingmkJHSBD,MFV FROM image/something/docker:2.6.1.566-978.7 testing"
```

Output:

```
image/something/docker:2.6.1.566-978.7
```

Or using different log string:

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /FROM image/) {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^image/) {print $i} }}' <<<"bdkjf asfjkklsdfsg FROM image/something/docker:2.6.1.566-978.7 testing"
```

Output:

```
image/something/docker:2.6.1.566-978.7
```